# Mysql : Selecting a monthly total occurence count

Tags: mysql, dql

In MySQL, I got a table similar to :

```
id  user_id date
1   1       2014-09-27
2   1       2014-11-05
3   1       2014-11-14
4   2       2014-12-03
5   1       2014-12-23
```

I would like to select the total monthly amount of people.

**ExpectedOutput : 4**

```
2014-09 = 1 user
2014-10 = 0 user
2014-11 = 1 user //user 1 is present twice in november, but I want him only once per month
2014-12 = 2 user

total expected = 4
```

**So far, my request is :**

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM myTable u1 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT id 
    FROM myTable u2 
    WHERE u2.user_id = u1.user_id
    AND DATE_SUB(u2.date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) > u1.date
);
```

It ouput the correct amount, but on my (not so heavy) table, it take hours to execute. Any hints to make this one lighter or faster ?

*Bonus :*

Since `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` is not available in DQL, is there any way to do it with a `Doctrine` `QueryBuilder` ?

Comment: You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT())` to count only the first time a value is appearing.

Comment: can you count distinct by period ? I said month, but it could be 15 min or any date range

Comment: I don't understand. You can change the periode yourself in the `DATE_SUB`, no ?

Comment: I misunderstood your comment then, where do you select distinct and on which value ? The subquery is called with `exists` so it'll return only first row, and the first query will have only distinct id, since there is no joins

Comment: You said `//user 1 is present twice in november, but I want him only once per month`, so you have to use `DISTINCT` in your first SELECT (line 1). And actually, I don't understand why the expected output is 5.

Comment: You're correct, I don't know why i wrote 5, it's 4. Anyway, the expected result in my query is the right one, i just want to faster it (like 10 times or more if possible)

Comment: I found the answer to you question. I posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

It should give you exactly what you need...

```sql
        SELECT
          EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dates) AS the_year,
          EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dates) AS the_month,
          COUNT( DISTINCT user_id ) AS total
        FROM 
          myTable
        GROUP BY
          EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dates),
          EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dates);
```

Comment: with join : `1 row in set (0.79 sec)`

with exists : `1 row in set (0.67 sec)`

Comment: That is weird... Do you have the user_id fields indexed on both tables?

Comment: Both tables are same, and yes there is an index on user_id

Comment: Seems a lot faster (0.7 to 0.01 ms), but i don't have my expected output. How to integrate the 'by `user_id`' condition ?

Comment: Yup @CrazyMenConnected, forgot my last comment, it seems to be the right answer. Thanks Seblor for the SUM wrapper but I'll accept Crazy answer if he adds it. (he already done the major part of the query)

Comment: I've changed my answer again, check if it fits your need now! Cheers!

Comment: I preferred  without your last edit, can i rollback to it and validate ?  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

For you problem, what I would do is :

- Creating a subrequst grouping the distinct sum of people by month
- Creating a request making the sum of the sub-result.

Here is [a working example (with your datas) sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/817cc/16/0)

And here is the request :

```
SELECT SUM(nb_people)
FROM (
-- This request return the number of distinct people in one month.
SELECT count(distinct(user_id)) AS nb_people, MONTH(`date`), YEAR(`date`)
FROM test
GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)
) AS subQuery
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id), YEAR(date) + '-' + MONTH(date)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```